# AngularJS: Http header

Tags: angularjs, http

I am newbie of angularJS. I want to add header in my http request but i am not understanding how? so far i've written this code.

Original code without header:

```
function saveUser(user, $http) {
        var token = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjYxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8zNC4yMDQuMjIyLjExM1wvYXBpXC91c2VycyIsImlhdCI6MTQ5NTE4MDY3MCwiZXhwIjoxNDk1MTg0MjcwLCJuYmYiOjE0OTUxODA2NzAsImp0aSI6IkdkNXdUSmZQMDRhcjc2UWIifQ.dKGZTysAibFbtruvSI7GwFV61kh43CX22g8-sRV9roQ";

        var url = __apiRoot + "/users/" + user.id;
        var dataObj = {
            payload: JSON.stringify(user),
            _method: "PUT",
        }
        return $http.post(url, dataObj);
    }
```

Now i am adding header to it, the code becomes like this:

```
function saveUser(user, $http) {
        var token = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjYxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8zNC4yMDQuMjIyLjExM1wvYXBpXC91c2VycyIsImlhdCI6MTQ5NTE4MDY3MCwiZXhwIjoxNDk1MTg0MjcwLCJuYmYiOjE0OTUxODA2NzAsImp0aSI6IkdkNXdUSmZQMDRhcjc2UWIifQ.dKGZTysAibFbtruvSI7GwFV61kh43CX22g8-sRV9roQ";

        var url = __apiRoot + "/users/" + user.id;
        var dataObj = {
            payload: JSON.stringify(user),
            _method: "PUT",
        }
        return $http({headers: {
                'Authorization': token
            }}).post(url, dataObj);
    }
```

By adding header, i am getting this error:

> angular.js:14525 Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url
>   must be a string or a $sce trusted object.  Received: undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax. Take a look at the angular documentation for [$http here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Your code should look like this:

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: __apiRoot + "/users/" + user.id,
      data: JSON.stringify(user)
      headers: {
       'Authorization': token
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
```